# Calculating Repeated Collaboration in R

Tags: r

Creating Data

```
REPC <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~OrganisationID, ~ProjectID,
    22905, 494993,
    9341, 494993,
    877, 504562,
    9221, 504874,
    867, 488182,
    238989, 488182,
    296, 488182,
    270858, 488182,
    867, 181688,
    22905, 181688,
    877, 181688,
    867, 504387,
    877, 504387,    
  )
```

I am currently trying to calculate the repeated collaboration of organizations, for which I require 2 values. I first intend to calculate the number of unique collaboration partners and the number of times an organization collaborated with each unique collaboration partner. Afterward, I want to calculate repeated collaboration, which can be expressed mathematically as 〖(∏Ri)〗^(1/N), where Ri is the number of R&D alliances the focal firm had with its i^th R&D partner and N is the total number of R&D partners. For example, a firm collaborated with 3 unique collaboration partners, he collaborated with partner 1, 3 times, partner 2, 4 times, partner 3, 5 times. This would lead to a repeated collaboration of (3*4*5)^1/3 = 3.91.

What I am trying to Achieve

```
REPC2 <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~OrganisationID, ~NoOfUniqueCollabPartners, ~NoOfCollabswith22905, ~NoOfCollabswith9341, ~NoOfCollabswith877, ~NoOfCollabswith9221, ~NoOfCollabswith867, ~NoOfCollabswith238989, ~NoOfCollabswith270858, ~NoOfCollabswith9221, ~RepeatedCollaboration, 
    22905, 3, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.33,
    9341, 1, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    877, 2, 1, 0, NA, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1.41,
    9221, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA,
    867, 5, 1, 0, 2, 0, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1.15,
    238989, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, 1, 1, 0.33,
    270858, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, NA, 1, 0.33,
    296, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0.33,
  )
```

Since a company cannot collaborate with itself the values should be either NA or zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just asking for the two values, I have skipped the collaboration matrix.

I have also made an assumption that there is no repeated row in your `tbl`.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

REPC <- as.data.table(REPC)

arr_org_ID <- unique(REPC[, OrganisationID]) # Array of unique organizations
N_org <- length(arr_org_ID) # Number of unique organizations
lst_proj <- lapply(arr_org_ID, function(id) {REPC[OrganisationID == id, unique(ProjectID)]}) # List of projects involved for each organization
lst_colab <- sapply((seq(N_org)), function(i) { # List of colaborators for each organization (including repeats)
  REPC[
    ProjectID %in% lst_proj[[i]] & OrganisationID != arr_org_ID[i],
    OrganisationID
  ]
})
dt_res <- lapply(seq(N_org), function(i) {
  arr_unique_colab = lst_colab[[i]] %>% unique
  N_unique_colab = arr_unique_colab %>% length # Number of unique collaborators
  # Calculating repeated collaboration ----
  {
    Rep_count = lapply(seq(N_unique_colab), function(j) {
      return(length(which(lst_colab[[i]] == arr_unique_colab[j])))
    }) %>% do.call(prod, .) %>% raise_to_power(1/N_unique_colab)
  }
  # Returning table ----
  {
    return(data.table(OrganisationID = arr_org_ID[i], N_unique_colab, Rep_count))
  }
}) %>% rbindlist
```

I am more confortable with `data.table` syntax so I have converted your `tbl`.

Comment: I presume you are new here. Please ponder with the code and try to understand why it works.

Comment: This works perfectly, u even caught my mistake with the 0.33 that should be 1. Will take me a very long time to understand why this works but I will do that and I am indeed new.

Comment: When you feel like it, it would be nice if you can upvote (and accept) my answer.